# OpenCV C++ Dilation Operator assistance

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCv in C++ in order to dilate an image containing edges (extracted using Canny) in order to achieve various edge levels. As seen in this image.

I am not sure which dilation structuring element to use in order to achieve this effect, or where the starting Point should be placed.

Meaning achieving (h),(i) from (g) and achieving (k),(l) from (j)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest :

```
Mat getStructuringElement(int shape, Size ksize, Point anchor=Point(-1,-1))
```

shape - Go for `CV_SHAPE_CUSTOM` By using so you can create your own shape structuring element.

But through morphology/dilation you cannot achieve h and k.

Comment: Hi Sriram, thank you for your reply. To achieve h and k I would remove the original values found in g and j once dilation is completed. My problem is the custom shape.. I've tried a simple line [0,0,0,0,1] but this doesn't achieve the desired effect as it will only work where the pixel to be 'moved' have vertical orientation...